# I want to develop BOX app using .net framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, box-api

I have developed a function with `BOX API` which can upload file to BOX folder. I have used `BOX.V2` and `.net framework 4.5` according to the documents required.

But I must use `.net framework 4.0` in the production environment. Is there any solutions to change the framework?

Can I develop BOX with .net framework? because there is no information about `.net framework 4.0` in BOX developer reference.

Thank you so much!!

Sisley

Comment: Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=vs-2019

Also I want to ask why can't you just update the solution to .net framework 4.0 in the first place than using framework 4.5 any reasons for that?

Comment: what is this _"BOX"_ anyway? share a link?

Comment: hi vasily.sib, https://developer.box.com. I should develop an app to upload file to box folder with OAuth2.0 .

Comment: hi NSDumb, thanks for your sharing. my question is that I must connect to BOX API. but as I know，I should use .net 4.5 when connect to BOX.

Comment: @SisleyTao please add `@` symbol before user names, so we get notified about your comment

Comment: @vasily.sib OK, thanks for your reminder. and i have no idea about this question, so I used java instead of C# to develop the app. thanks for your all help.